# Unity camera script broken. Camera only rotates when it wants to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 CameraPosition;
    private float Xrot;
    private float yrot;
    public float Sens = -1f;
    bool rotating = false;
    private Vector3 Rotate;

    public float CameraSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CameraPosition = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            rotating = true;

        }
        else
        {
            rotating = false;
        }


        yrot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        Xrot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

        if (rotating)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(Xrot, yrot * Sens, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            CameraPosition.z += CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            CameraPosition.z -= CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            CameraPosition.x += CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            CameraPosition.x -= CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            CameraPosition.y += CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            CameraPosition.y -= CameraSpeed / 100;
        }
        



        this.transform.position = CameraPosition;
    }

}
```

tried everything even chatgpt but nothing helped had to resort to stack overflow. The camera only rotates when it wants to and seems to only rotate on the frame that the right mouse button is clicked, but otherwise is not.
I need it to be able to move freely when the right mouse button is held down.

Comment: because thats what you told it to do - by setting it to false if not the frame the mouse button was down

Comment: i want it to stop rotating with my mouse once i release the right mouse button. Unless the if statement  only works for the frame on which i initally press down the left mouse button this should work?

Comment: I know what you want. Im telling you what you told it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> [`GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) vs [`GetMouseButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html)

As BugFinder told you, the first (and what you currently use) is only true for the first frame, the second as long as you hold down the button.

You can btw shorten this and simply directly assign

```
rotating = Input.GetMouseButton(1);
```

or even condense the entire block:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    var yrot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    var xrot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(xrot, yrot * Sens, 0);
}
```

---

Then finally you should not use [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) for continuous rotations!

> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the
> Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles.
> Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation
> using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite
> different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if
> you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
>
> To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with
> rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading
> .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a
> rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see
> the Quaternion * operator.

In your case rather use [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

```
transform.Rotate(0, xrot * sens, 0, Space.World);
transform.Rotate(-yrot * sens, 0, 0, Space.Local);
```

This basically equals doing (and is a shorthand for - see [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/7c95a72366b5ed9b6d9e804de8b5e869c962f5a9/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs#L162))

```
// Yeah rotations are always a bit tricky ;)
transform.rotation *=  (Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * Quaternion.Euler(0, xrot * sense, 0) * transformn.rotation);
transform.localRotation *= Quaterinon.Euler(-yrot * sens, 0, 0);
```

Note

- I switched the X and Y. Usually you would want your mouse movement in X rotate around the Y axis and wise versa.
- I separated the rotation into Y-axis in world space while the X-axis rotates in local space